# About optimization with Renyi divergence

Tags: it.information-theory, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming, information-geometry

- Can someone link me to some pedagogic example of computing the Renyi divergence between two discrete/continuous distributions? Like examples where someone has been able to obtain a neat closed form or such answer?
- Is there any example of doing an optimization on Renyi divergence? Like given a distribution and some constraints on a second one, being able to write down the second distribution such that their mutual $\alpha$-Renyi divergence is minimized. Is there such an example?

Answer (score 4):

For the requested examples see [Rényi Divergence and Kullback-Leibler Divergence](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2459) (2012).

• *Two continuous distributions:* Equation 10 gives the Rényi divergence between two Gaussian distributions (mean $\mu_i$, variance $\sigma_i$):

$$
  D_\alpha\Big({\cal N}(\mu_0,\sigma_0^2)\|{\cal N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)\Big)
    = \frac{\alpha(\mu_1 - \mu_0)^2}{2\sigma_\alpha^2}
      + \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log\left(
      \frac{\sigma_\alpha}{\sigma_0^{1-\alpha}\sigma_1^\alpha}\right),
$$
for $\sigma_\alpha^2 = (1-\alpha)\sigma_0^2 + \alpha
\sigma_1^2 > 0$

• *Two discrete distributions:* Figures 2 and 3 show the Rényi divergence $D_\alpha(P||Q)$ for fixed $Q$ as $P$ varies over a sample space containing two or three elements.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And any example of doing the kind of optimization that I was looking for?

Comment: for $\alpha=2$ there exist closed-form expressions for mixtures of Gaussians, which have been used in an optimization problem in http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2921653/

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for examples where one is given a distribution and one is trying to find another distribution so that some $\alpha-$Renyi divergence between them is minimized. Know of any?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, [the MSc thesis by Manuel Gil](https://%20qspace.library.queensu.ca/handle/1974/6680) provides/derives closed form expressions for Renyi divergences associated with several of the continuous distributions.

Comment: The link is dead but I think this is what you are referring to: https://qspace.library.queensu.ca/handle/1974/6680